# Can you asist me with my SensHat Python code?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I would like to program the following thing on my SenseHat with Python:

When on the Senshat the middle button is pressed a timer starts and three LEDs light up. Blue (Catcher), Green (Point1), Red (Point2).
The goal is to move the blue LED with the joystick over Green and the Red.
When arrived at Red the time is stopped and shown on the display.
If Red is touched before Green then it is a fail.

I work with [The New Sense HAT Emulator](https://trinket.io/sense-hat).
So far I got it to show the points but when I added the Catcher it refreshes the points out.

The timer I have not yet implemented.
This is a school project but after 6 hours of trying I did not know where else to ask.

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat, ACTION_PRESSED, ACTION_HELD, ACTION_RELEASED
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from signal import pause

sense = SenseHat()

# Variables ---------------------------
x = 3
y = 3
white = (255, 255, 255)
blank = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)


# Functions ------------------------------

def clamp(value, min_value=0, max_value=7):
    return min(max_value, max(min_value, value))

def pushed_up(event):
    global y
    if event.action != ACTION_RELEASED:
        y = clamp(y - 1)

def pushed_down(event):
    global y
    if event.action != ACTION_RELEASED:
        y = clamp(y + 1)

def pushed_left(event):
    global x
    if event.action != ACTION_RELEASED:
        x = clamp(x - 1)

def pushed_right(event):
    global x
    if event.action != ACTION_RELEASED:
        x = clamp(x + 1)

def refresh():
    sense.clear()
    sense.set_pixel(x, y, 0, 0, 255)  

def make_point1():
  x = randint(0, 7)
  y = randint(0, 7)
  point1 = [x, y]
  sense.set_pixel(x, y, green)

  
def make_point2():
  x = randint(0, 7)
  y = randint(0, 7)
  point1 = [x, y]
  sense.set_pixel(x, y, red)
  
sense.stick.direction_up = pushed_up
sense.stick.direction_down = pushed_down
sense.stick.direction_left = pushed_left
sense.stick.direction_right = pushed_right
sense.stick.direction_any = refresh
pause()

  # Main program ------------------------

make_point1()
make_point2()
```

Comment: The issue is that your `refresh` clears the whole screen. You have two options. 1. Store the position of the red and green LEDs and redisplay them in the `refresh` function after you've cleared the LEDs or 2. Don't clear the whole display in `refresh` but remember the previous position of the blue led and just clear that one before displaying the new position.

Comment: Thank you I think I will try to go with the second idea.

Comment: That would probably be best. Also there's a typo in `make_point2()` where you set a `point1` variable instead of `point2`. You'll need to make these global when you want to use them. Just a suggestion but you could consider making this a single function that takes the colour as a parameter and returns the point position. Then in your main code you can write `point1 = make_point(green)` and `point2 = make_point(red)`.